# Можно ли делать один post запрос внутри другого?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Правильно ли делать один post запрос внутри другого? И если нет - то можно ли как-нибудь передать клиенту сразу 2 ответа от сервера? У меня сейчас такой код:

```
$.post("auth.php", {'login': login, 'password': pass, 'remember': remember},
                function(data){
                    if(data == "false"){
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                        var div = document.querySelector("#div");
                        div.innerHTML = "Неправильный логин или пароль";
                    }else if(data == "true"){
                        $.post("auth.php", {"idl": login},
                            function(data){
                            alert(data);
                                window.location.href = "profile.html?"+data;
                            }
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Может заменить его get-запросом?

Answer (score 2):

У вас не 2 запроса в одном, а 2 запроса, идущие один за другим.  В принципе это нормально.

Функция идущая третьим аргументом в  `$.post` выполняется после того как запрос был совершен.